# Best video/audio editing software for Windows 7 64-bit to make the volume on different clips the same and joining them without quality loss

Tags: video-editing

I'm looking for a program that can analyze the volume on various videos and then make them all the same and a program that can join them without quality loss. I've tried a lot of free ones but they never worked. Price doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I use Sony Vegas Studio and it's 100 bucks, does many things like his big brother Vegas Pro. It recognizes many modern/HD/HQ files too, so you may work with the hi-quality projects. Of course there are many applications but I prefer Sony Vegas.

Comment: Why does it require Quicktime? I hate Quicktime. Does it analyze sound and give a numerical number to which one can choose another number for the volume to be altered to...? Any other good apps?

Comment: I hate Quicktime too but it's Apple's made, so Sony cannot redistribute their codecs.

Comment: Ahhh...does the $44 version have what I'm looking for? I'm interested primarily in messing with Youtube clips--making the sound the same and then joining...not making my own or anything. Also, does the audio editor just "normalize" or is it more "truer"...?

Comment: Just give the demo a try. About the sound: Search for "sony vegas automatic volume leveling", Google & YouTube contains priceless info. At least you can manually adjust the volume for each part you merge, it's extremely simple.

Comment: Is the demo with limited features? Oh, so you're saying the $44 can only do it manually? Downloading right now....hope it isn't a steep learning curve. Oh, how do I know if I have a Windows-compatible sound card?

Comment: Crap, the program's icons, buttons are tiny on my monitor! I've got a 24" widescreen with the resolution on the recommended one. I've noticed that I have this problem with some software. How do I solve it? I can't read anthing; the whole program has a grey background o it.